# Binding string instead of ImageSource with Dependency property WPF button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I have my code below with `string` type instead of `ImageSource` for dependency property and it's working only if I use `ImageSource` and not if I use string instead. Where I have gone wrong in below code?

**ButtonTile.cs**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCarProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyCar", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonTile));

public string MyCar 
{ 
    get{ return (string)GetValue(MyCarProperty); } 
    set{ SetValue(MyCarProperty, value);} 
}
```

StyleResource page .xaml

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyCar,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
```

In Window page .xaml

```
<mybuton:ButtonTile Style="{StaticResource MyCarStyle}" MyCar="Images\AddStock.ico.png">
```

Comment: The property holds an ImageSource. Why would you want to declare it as string? That said, `Images\AddStock.ico.png` is perhaps not a valid file or assembly resource path when the TemplatedParent Binding is evaluated.

Comment: @Clemens just updating you, the above code builds and execute without error, may be you need to add AddStock.ico.png in Images folder. I wanted to declare as string because to know flexibility of code, so that I can reuse for other requirement.

Comment: Flexibility for what? Something that is not an image? Is all your above XAML in the same assembly or in multiple assemblies?

Comment: yes flexibility for not an image type also. Above XALM is in same assembly only.

Comment: Provided that the image file is part of the project, and its Build Action is set to Resource, try a full [Resource File Pack UR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris)I: `MyCar="pack://application:,,,/Images/AddStock.ico.png"`.

Comment: @Clemens yes it's now working indeed with `MyCar="pack://application:,,,/Images/AddStock.ico.png"` . Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why the full URI seems to be necessary. It works fine for me with just Images\AddStock.ico.png